# Error when initialize a function pointer that is a struct member

Tags: c++, struct

Given the following struct with a filename and a functionpointer:

```
static struct thread {
    const char *const filename;
    ssize_t (*in)(struct thread *, void *, size_t);

}
```

and the function

```
int MyClass::read_wrap(struct stThread *t, void *buf, size_t nbytes)
{
    return read(t->fd, buf, nbytes);
}
```

I try to assign the function `read_wrap` to the function pointer member in a struct object:

```
int main (void)
{

thread myThread;
myThread.in = read_wrap;

}
```

But I get the error:

```
error: cannot convert MyClass::read_wrap’ from type ‘int (MyClass::)(stThread*, void*, size_t) {aka int (MyClass::)(stThread*, void*, unsigned int)}’ to type ‘int (*)(MyClass*, void*, size_t) {aka int (*)(stThread*, void*, unsigned int)}’
```

I mean, the struct is expecting a function pointer and I thought when I pass it the name of the function, that this is somehow cast into a fp?!
This code is from C and compiles fine with gcc. 
Thanks for the help!

Comment: the t->fd function is member function type, this is different for just function pointer type

Answer (score 1):

Member function pointers have different types to normal function pointers. As you can see from the error, the type of a member function pointer to `read_wrap` is actually:

```
int (MyClass::*)(stThread*, void*, size_t)
```

The important part is `MyClass::` which makes it incompatible with a normal function pointer. This member function pointer must be called on some instance of `MyClass`.

However, since your `read_wrap` function doesn't even seem to use any non-static members of `MyClass`, there isn't a reason to have it as a non-static member function. Either make it a free function or make it a static member and your error will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Your are initializing an unbound function `ordinary function`  pointer (`type ‘int (*)(MyClass*, void*, size_t) {aka int (*)(stThread*, void*, unsigned int)}’`) with a non static member function address (`type ‘int (MyClass::)(stThread*, void*, size_t) {aka int (MyClass::)(stThread*, void*, unsigned int)}’` ). The Type of your declaration needs to be changed to match with your initialized value.

Try changing

```
ssize_t (*in)(struct thread *, void *, size_t);
```

To

```
ssize_t (MyClass::*in)(struct thread *, void *, size_t);
```

Comment: If you make that change, you'll also need to somehow provide a `MyClass` object to call the member function on. Since the function doesn't access any class members, making it static, or a non-member, is probably a better option.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: I believe, OP question is just a stripped down version of a bigger problem. So assuming `the function doesn't access any class members`, may not be correct. But any case, let have the choice with OP based on the use case. And Yes, what you mentioned is a design issue. If a function is trivial enough that it does not access any class members, it should be a non member function. The function pointer part of the question comes much later in the scenario. Please let me know if you think otherwise.